Connect Tabular Editor 2 to Azure Databricks
We are using the free version of Tabular Editor (2.19).
We would like to import tables directly from Azure Databricks.
in tabular editor I get to the interface below

I have added both a User DSN and a System DSN based on the Simba Spark ODBC Driver.
System DSN = Databricks-dev-2
When I use the test connection for these DSN I get a "Success" message.
However, none of these DSN show up.
I have also tried writting a connection string "Driver=C:\Program Files\Simba Spark ODBC Driver;Host=adb-..azuredatabricks.net;Port=443;HTTPPath=sql/protocolv1/o//--;SSL=1;ThriftTransport=2;UID=token;PWD=**" But i then get the following error "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft]{ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified."
I have also tried clicking build in order to automatically build the connection string. I pick the .dsn file that I've successfully tested the connection on. But get the error "Failed to call the ODBC driver connection utility"
I have followed the following instructions and installed the ODBC driver for 64bit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/integrations/odbc/download

Late to the party but it's because those connectors are 64bit and tabular editor 2 is 32bit.
